# PySNMP Fetch SNMP variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, snmp, pysnmp

I have used following code snippet to get SNMP variable but always I am getting No SNMP response received before timeout . No firewall was enabled and got same error when tried in my personal laptop . does demo.snmplabs.com is working ? please advice.
is there any other fetch snmp details ?
Sample code from https://pysnmp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick-start.html

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *



iterator = getCmd(
    SnmpEngine(),
    CommunityData('public', mpModel=0),
    UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
    ContextData(),
    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('SNMPv2-MIB', 'sysDescr', 0))
)

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(iterator)

if errorIndication:
    print(errorIndication)

elif errorStatus:
    print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                        errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))

else:
    for varBind in varBinds:
        print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

Comment: snmplabs.com is no longer owned by whoever managed the pysnmp project

Comment: You should now switch to https://www.pysnmp.com as my team revived the project.